# Android device stucks in obtaining IP address from Windows hotspot

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, android

I have two Android devices (lets call them A1 and A2) and a Windows 10 laptop. My Windows laptop does not have an Internet connection; so first I create a WIFI hotspot using A1 and share it with my Windows 10 laptop. Now I want to connect to a VPN on my laptop and share the connection with A2 using ICS. I create a hotspot using my laptop. However, when trying to connect to the hotspot using A2 it gives this error message "Can not obtain IP address".

I tried a couple of different solutions to no avail:

1. I disabled Windows firewall
2. Disabled random MAC on A2 and used device MAC
3. Tried another device instead of A2
4. Tried to use static IP addresses

The strange thing is that **when I test the same procedure on another Windows 10 laptop it works!** Finally, I installed Wireshark and captured DHCP packets between A2 and my laptop. A2 sends DHCPDiscover; but no answer is sent back by Windows device. I searched the issue, bu no one seems to know the answer...

Comment: Win10 hotspot operates with WPA2-PSK/AES. Did you test A2 device with A1 and how old the A2 device is? Also, from my own experience this feature depends on drivers for the WiFi NIC laptop uses. For example, same laptop could be a hotspot when running W8, but hotspot was not available on same machine with W10. I personally use Connectify Hotspot software when needed, which is great (paid license though). Age issue can go both ways - Android 12 devices may not be backward compatible with older W10 running devices, too. Drivers Updated?

Comment: @AcePL: Thx dear Ace. I will test Connectify Hotspot. However, I do not think age or driver version is an issue here; because I have another laptop with exactly the same configuration and everything works on it.

Comment: Well, from cursory searching the web for the issue I found that Windows 10 hotspot does not play well with android. There are possible solutions to the issue, of which two most prominent is to check PC config to make sure only connection created for hotspot should be available for sharing with other devices, other is to move to a static TCP/IP address for Android devices, because quite often W10 DHCP works with some issues. I found also that AV may be the culprit, so disabling that also helps. Connectify may have free version, I paid for it because it's more reliable and can be configured.

Comment: I have already disabled the AV to no avail :(. Thx a lot anyway.

Comment: Dear @AcePL I have bought and installed Connectify. It solved my problem. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AcePL I installed [Connectify hotspot](https://connectify.me/). It solved my problem. However, there should be other possible solutions that do not need buying and installing 3rd party software.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree. But this is a problem with closed-source software - Microsoft decided to go with fixed settings feature, which could be fixed easily by community otherwise.
I don't complain though. Connectify paid for itself many times over - especially since I travel a lot and, for example, making your own hotspot in a hotel where only wired LAN network is available saves a ton of money by not cursing and looking for coverage.

Answer (score 1):

For me I have to always 1. Go to the connection that is providing the internet, and Properties -> Share and share it with the virtual adapter aka hotspot (usually called like Local Area Connection *5, some number).

Also, other times it is caused by the Lan card steal the IP address for some reason, I had a USB lan card plugged in and it was interfering, while I wasn't using it.

Comment: This is the correct solution - sharing my Ethernet to Wi-Fi didn't work, but `Local Area Connection *#` (in my case, `*4`), yes!